# Selenium Button click without ID or CLASSNAME

Tags: c#, selenium

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lj82B.png)I need to click a button without ID or classname. how do I do that?

the button is

```
input type="button" class="button L T T_disconn" value="Bağlantıyı Kes" onclick="doDisConn(2, [1,1,1,0,0,0]);"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS or xpath Selector. Try CSS for your requirement

```
driver.findelement(by.cssselector(#wan_table td input[type='button'][value='Bağlantıyı Kes'])).click();
```

if .click() doesn't work, try importing `import org.openqa.selenium.Keys` and perform the action using Send Keys.

```
driver.findelement(by.cssselector(#wan_table td input[type='button'][value='Bağlantıyı Kes'])).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

Comment: IWebElement find = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[type='button'][value='Bağlantıyı Kes']"));
            find.Click();

like this did not work

Comment: along with the selector, I have added a way to use sendkeys to perform the click

Answer (score 0):

using an xpath identifier.

```
//input[@class='button L T T_disconn']
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@class='button L T T_disconn']")).click();
```

or

```
//input[@value='Bağlantıyı Kes']
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@value='Bağlantıyı Kes']")).click();
```

or

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[contains(@class, 'Kes')]")).click();
```

Based on your image with the html there is reference to an iframe at the bottom. If the button you want to click is in an iframe, you can use this to get access.

```
    public static void SwitchToIframe(string frameName)
    {
        try
        {
            driver.SwitchTo().Frame(frameName);
        }
        catch (NoSuchFrameException)
        {
            try
            {
                driver.SwitchTo().Frame(frameName);
            }
            catch (NoSuchFrameException)
            {
                LogFunctions.WriteError("Could not switch into IFrame");
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then to switch back....

```
    public static void SwitchToMainContent()
    {
        driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
    }
```

Comment: IWebElement find = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@class='button L T T_disconn']"));
            find.Click();

did not work either

Comment: Additional information: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@class='button L T T_disconn']"}

everything works fine but this button, 6 hours cant fix this problem

Comment: is it on an iframe by chance or popup? Do you have a link to the page?

Comment: its my routers control panel which is 192.168.1.1 its in table, I think its javascript button when you press "Bağlantıyı Kes" which means cut the connection, it changes to "connect again"

Comment: can you add some more html for this?

Comment: added pictuer to the main post

Comment: added another way to search for it. If this is a popup, you will need to switch to it most likely. If it is in an iframe, you will also need to switch to it. You have not said if it is a popup or not.

Comment: just as a heads up, at the very bottom of your image there is partial iframe text so It looks like this could be your issue. I am going to add some code for you in my answer for this.

Comment: I added 1 more picture of the whole HTML and page. with this code you've provided driver.switchto() and LogFunctions.WriteError does not work, do I need to include library or something?